# Is it a good idea for a prospective MS student to mention in his SOP that he has good expertise on software like Microsoft office?

Tags: graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose

I heard that information technology is a great tool to do research.I have good expertise on Microsoft office (Office,Excel,Access,Power point,Output) and graphical software like Adobe Photoshop.Could I mention these learning skills in my SOP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These can be useful research tools, but **be specific about how your expertise in Office and Photoshop can help you with your proposed research project.** Don't just say that you are good at Office and Photoshop generally. I suspect most people have some knowledge about how to use them anyway and it won't be valuable information for the admission committee.

Answer (score 9):

No, because it does not distinguish you from other applicants nor explain *why* you would a good fit in the program to which you are applying.  The expectation in 2015 is that everyone likely to be in graduate school, and even undergraduates, can use the standard desktop software with enough proficiency to get things done.  If specialized software, something like Mathematica or SPSS, is needed in your field, the assumption is that you either already know about it or you'll figure it out.

If you haven't already done so, have a look at this: [(Master's Degree) What are they 'precisely' looking for in a Statement of Purpose, and does a SOP matter when one has excellent GPA?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/34616/masters-degree-what-are-they-precisely-looking-for-in-a-statement-of-purpos/34627#34627)

Answer (score 3):

This information would fit better in your CV/resume. But even there, you should only list software that is relevant to your field. For example, if you're not applying to an art or design program, Photoshop is almost certainly irrelevant.