# Is blogging experience (on medium) relevant on the CV for PhD CS Admissions? (US)

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, cv, undergraduate

**Background:** Undergrad applying to PhD CS Programs in the US

I had done a blogging internship in my sophomore year and I had written 10 blogs during the tenure. All the articles are relevant to my domain and are balanced between technicality and general information on the domain.

**Why I want to put it in my CV:**

- The blogs were supervised by someone who has been a "linkedin" top speaker and I have his recommendation as well on my page.
- The blogs were generally well received (but nothing extra-ordinary).
- I exactly have space for one more "small" component in the "experience" section of my resume.
- The other option I have is working part of a start up for a month but I have nothing to show for that as I am not allowed to.

**Short CV Background:**

- 2 pages
- First page: only undergrad uni details and "experience (research internships)
- Second page: Projects, External collaborations, Awards, Skills.
- It's complete and organized with only that small portion of space remaining.

**Actual Questions:**

1. Will it help showcase any part of my expertise? (Communication, writing, English in general)
2. Is it relevant to the Admission panel? (or would I be wasting their time by adding this?)

I don't plan on mentioning it anywhere else like SOP, LOR, SOH (Personal History statement).

Comment: Related: [Should I mention my blog in my SOP?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/34663/should-i-mention-my-blog-in-my-sop)

Comment: Sorry about that, I somehow missed that post. It did not show up while writing this either. Also, this is a little bit different. So I feel it could generate a different insight!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost any experience is useful on a CV, provided that you can link it to the job you are applying for in a sensible way (this is nearly always possible). It is likely that all candidates have similar diplomas, so the "extra" things you did besides your degree are very valuable. Being able to demonstrate that you are a skilled technical writer and science communicator will almost certainly help.

Mentioning "medium" by name has no value (see also below), but the fact that you have written well received articles on a weblog will improve your CV.

There is a good chance that the hiring committee does not know "medium", and if they do, they probably know that a lot of very bad articles are published on medium (as well as some good ones). If you get through a first screening the hiring committee could be interested in reading your articles to see if they are any good: it would help to provide them with a link to the list of articles.

Comment: My guess would be "positive impact but small". But neglecting to mention the experience would be a mistake and a lost opportunity.

Comment: @Louic Thank you for the insight! Especially regarding medium. I had not thought about that thoroughly. I will make sure to provide a link!

Comment: Thank you @Buffy. That helped me clear my mind!